# Installing Jenkins plugin (mercurial) in Docker shows in plugins folder but not in Jenkins itself

Tags: plugins, jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, dockerfile

Problem: I can't seem to successfully install the mercurial plugin to jenkins using the Dockerfile and plugins.txt combination.

What I've done so far:

I have a Dockerfile that's loading Jenkins. It has the following lines:

```
FROM jenkins:1.642.1
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
```

My plugins.txt has this line:

```
mercurial:1.54
```

When I build the image and run the container, everything seems to work, there are no errors or complaints. But the Mercurial plugin isn't marked as installed when I go to Manage Plugins, and if I try to make a build, Mercurial isn't an option under Source Code Management.

[image: Jenkins plugin manager]

[image: Source control options in Jenkins]

I've tried going to:

```
<jenkins ip address>:8080/reload
```

As well as the "Reload Configuration from Disk" option in Manage Jenkins. Mercurial still isn't visibly installed after either of these.

I've also done this on the command line:

```
docker exec -i -t container bash
ls /var/jenkins_home/plugins/
```

[image: Output from ls of plugins]

And at this point I'm totally confused, because there's mercurial, mercurial.jpi and mercurial.jpi.pinned right there in the list. Does anyone have any ideas on this? I would like to have Mercurial installed on Jenkins as soon as it's loaded from the Dockerfile without having to do it manually...

Also, I tried doing this with git-changelog as well to see if another plugin would work better, and had the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see on the [Mercurial Plugin wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin), the plugin currently has four mandatory dependencies, and one optional:

- credentials
- matrix-project
- multiple-scms (optional)
- ssh-credentials
- scm-api

The plugin installation mechanism that you're using with the Jenkins Docker image does not automatically install dependent plugins for you, as mentioned in the documentation for the [`jenkins` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/):

> All plugins need to be listed as there is no transitive dependency resolution.

Therefore you need to additionally list those plugins, and any of *their* transitive dependencies, in your `plugins.txt` file.

At the moment, the simplest way to get the full list would be to start your container (potentially without `plugins.txt`), and then install the Mercurial plugin via the Plugin Manager, which will be installed along with all of its dependencies.  Then you can see a list of which plugins are required via `$JENKINS_HOME/plugins`.

Comment: Thanks, I was struggling with this for hours!